# pass error by reference: const boost::system::error_code& err

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to call a completion handler with my own error code, but the signature for the argument is:

```
const boost::system::error_code& err
```

And I'm worried about the lifetime of the error_code I construct, especially in relation to async handlers, chained handlers, io_service.post, and careless propagation of a reference to a stack based error code that has gone out of scope.

I could try something like this:

```
const boost::system::error_code err = 
    boost::system::errc::make_error_code(boost::system::errc::bad_message);
handler(&err);
```

but it seems a bit gruesome not to pass by value; especially if I want to use io_service.post

Is something like this using lambdas the best way? (I could also make the error in the lambda)

```
const boost::system::error_code err = 
    boost::system::errc::make_error_code(boost::system::errc::bad_message);
io_service.post([error](){ handler(&err); }
```

and is this safe? Leak-free?

```
handler(boost::system::errc::make_error_code(boost::system::errc::bad_message));
```

Comment: don't worry about passing by value. it's extremely cheap for an error_code. they are designed to be passed this way.

Comment: It's lifetime I'm worried about more than efficiency. Pass-by-reference is fine until the referenced instance goes out of scope

Comment: For what it is worth, the `error_code` Asio passes to all user supplied handlers are on the stack.  Also, it may be worth considering invoking the handler via [`asio_handler_invoke()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_invoke.html) to allow for custom invocation strategies to be used.

Answer (score 5):

Even though the handler function signature takes a const ref error_code, any handler object which stores the error code should store a copy of it. If you don't do this you will (as you are concerned about) eventually run into lifetime problems in anything other than the most trivial asio-based program.

C++ function objects actually function this way by default - you have to deliberately pass them reference_wrappers to get them to store references, and for good reason. It's much easier to reason about a program that passes copies. And in a multi-threaded program, passing copies more often than not gives better performance, because there is no mutex contention or cache-flushing to worry about.

In addition, `error_code` objects are *extremely* lightweight. They are faster to copy by value than to use by reference.

So, in summary, don't do this:

```
const boost::system::error_code err = 
  boost::system::errc::make_error_code(boost::system::errc::bad_message);
handler(&err);
```

do this:

```
handler(make_error_code(boost::system::errc::bad_message));
```

don't do this:

```
const boost::system::error_code err = 
boost::system::errc::make_error_code(boost::system::errc::bad_message);
io_service.post([error](){ handler(&err); }
```

do this:

```
auto err = make_error_code(boost::system::errc::bad_message);
io_service.post([err](){ handler(err); }
```

or this:

```
io_service.post(std::bind(hander, make_error_code(boost::system::errc::bad_message));
```

or this:

```
io_service.post([] {
    handler(make_error_code(boost::system::errc::bad_message)); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer; Can you help reassure me that this doesn't pass a reference to a temporary instance on the stack?
handler(make_error_code(boost::system::errc::bad_message)); (on account of still being passed by reference)

Comment: it may or may not pass a reference, but if the handler needs a copy, it will take a copy from the reference immediately. the only references that handler objects/functions should store and forward are those of the input and output buffers (it is explicitly documented that asio buffers must outlast the handler object - which we achieve by passing a copy of a shared_ptr to the buffer when we construct the handler)